# how can i convert multi page and single page tiff from all compression types to group 4 compression with libtiff.net?

Tags: c#, libtiff.net

i have hundred of multipage and single page tiffs with all kind of compression and i want to convert them to group 4 with libtiff.net and if possible with TiffCP in c#. i try to do this by "add reference" in Microsoft Visual Studio and `using Bitmiracle.TiffCP;` but i don't know how should i use this namespace.

how can i solve that?

Comment: Greetings. It would be appreciated if you showed what you have tried. It helps users answer questions and help find solutions to problems you may be having

Comment: i do that by "add reference" in Microsoft visual studio and 'using Bitmiracle.TiffCP;'and but i don't know how can i do that with TiffCP

Answer (score 1):

TiffCP is an **executable** packaged with the binaries when you [download](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff.net_bin.zip).  Note in that directory >> **TiffCP.exe**.

Here is an implmentation i did for an example:

```
            System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\PathToExe\TiffCP.exe";
            string path1 = @"C:\PathToImage\image.tiff";
            string path2 = @"C:\PathToImage\imagePage1.tiff";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + path1 + "\"" + ",0 \"" + path2 + "\"";
            p.Start();
            string t = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```